# Restrict tag insertion in XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, jaxp

My question is related to Java. I have an xml which is initially valid as per xsd, I have used DOM parser and got a Document object out of it (I am using JAXP). Now, I want to disallow insertion of invalid xml element. So, when I try doing something like appendChild() I should get an exception if the element is invalid as per schema.

I have set the schema at the factory level before getting the dom.  However, it seems to be fine with insertion of invalid elements. I only get to know that my document is incorrect when I am using validation api to check the validity of Document but that is happening at the end.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Company xmlns="uri:Trial">
  <Business>
    <APAC>tns:APAC</APAC>
  </Business>  

  <NonBusiness>
    <Facilities>tns:Facilities</Facilities>
  </NonBusiness>
</Company>
```

The xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="uri:Trial"
    xmlns:tns="uri:Trial" elementFormDefault="qualified"     attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="Company" type="tns:MyComplexType"></element>


    <complexType name="MyComplexType">
        <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:Business"></element>
            <element ref="tns:NonBusiness"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <element name="Business" type="tns:BusinessType"></element>




    <element name="APAC" type="string"></element>

    <element name="AUS" type="string"></element>

    <element name="NonBusiness" type="tns:NonBusinessType"></element>

    <element name="Facilities" type="string"></element>



    <complexType name="BusinessType">
            <choice>
            <element ref="tns:APAC"></element>
            <element ref="tns:AUS"></element>
        </choice>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="NonBusinessType">
        <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:Facilities"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

The java

public class MainJAXPValidation {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File fxml = new File ("xmls/Trial.xml");
    File fxsd = new File ("xmls/Trial.xsd");



    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(fxsd));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setSchema(schema);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
//  dbf.setValidating(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(fxml);

    Node tempNode = doc.createElement("SomeChild");

    doc.appendChild(tempNode);

    DOMSource ds = new DOMSource(doc);

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    validator.validate(ds);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest an alternative...
Have a custom class say, MyDocument which extends DocumentImpl.
In your class, override the appendChild and other necessary methods.
In your overridden method, you can do the validation and throw runtime exceptions.

```
  import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl;
public class MyDocument extends DocumentImpl{

    Document document;
    Schema schema;

    public MyDocument(File xmlFile,File schemaFile) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        this.document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        this.schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaFile));

    }


    @Override
    public Node appendChild(Node newChild) throws DOMException {
//Validation    
return super.appendChild(newChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hirak, I guess it means that there is nothing available out-of-the-box.

Comment: I afraid none... atleast in the xerces library that comes with Java. I am not sure if realtime validation is done in other xml parsing libraries like JDOM etc... but chances are low.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way for you to do that in JAXP. With DOM, each and every `Node` is also an `EventTarget`, so you can register an `EventListener` to your `Document` and work from there (your listener could throw an exception if a disallowed insertion takes place).

Of course, you may wish to attach an `EventListener` to a "narrower" scope than the entire document, for performance reasons.

Here's a good place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?org/w3c/dom/events/EventListener.html